# How to tag questions specifically about the classic DVI-producing latex compiler?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We have a [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex) tag to refer about pdf(La)TeX, but no actual way to tag a question specifically for the classic `latex` or `tex` compilers. For example I don't know how to tag questions ala "How to use PNG images with `latex`". In contrast, a question like "How to use EPS images with `pdflatex`" can be tagged with [eps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eps) [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex).

Using [dvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi) would be a workaround, but after all [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf), which is about the PDF format per se, would be wrong for [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex) related questions.

Should we create a [dvitex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvitex) tag or similar?

---

#### May 7th 2012:

I now created the [dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode) with synonyms [dvimode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvimode) (for easier typing) and [tex-dvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-dvi) (alternative suggestion). Please use it as follows:

- Questions about the `latex` compiler which outputs `.dvi` files should be tagged with [dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode).
- Questions in general about *producing* DVI files should be also tagged with [dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode).
- Questions about the DVI format itself, like how to convert it to a different format, should be tagged with [dvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi).
- It would be possible to use both tags together if the question is about producing and converting DVI files etc.

This is analog to the existing tags [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex) and [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest using [dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode).

Today usually the DVI mode of pdfTeX is used. pdfTeX is the default engine in modern TeX distributions and capable of producing both PDF and DVI.

[dvi-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-mode) makes clear that we

- don't mean DVI as format, which is covered by the [dvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi) tag,
- actually deal with a mode of a TeX engine rather than a non-pdfTeX engine. `tex` as part of the name is not required on a TeX site.

Comment: That's makes perfectly sense. I support this proposal.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like `{dvitex}` since it's not used in any other context. Can we have symbols in tags?  If so, how about

- `{tex+dvi}`

**Edit:** It appears that we can't have `+` in a tag, but we can have hyphens, so instead:

- `{tex-dvi}`

Comment: BTW: you can write `[tag:thetagname]` to get {thetagname} with a link to the tag page.

Comment: We can have `-` in tag names (e.g. [tag:tikz-pgf]) but `+` seems to be reserved because it is used for the URL encoding.

Comment: I'm against the use of [tag:dvips] because its really just about that program. As a variation of your first suggestion we could use [tag:tex-dvi].

Comment: @Martin I guess I agree about `dvips`; I'll remove that option so that people can vote just on the `tex-dvi` suggestion.